# Document Library Web Part size reseting to Medium size

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, document-library, modern-experience, sitepages

Recently, while building a page with SharePoint Modern, I noticed I am not able to use the automatic size for Document Library web part. After selecting it and hitting apply, the changes are visible, but if I go back to edit the web part or publish the page, that web part won't maintain the automatic size selection, it revert back to 'Medium - about 15 items' (default size).

Changing to Automatic size, applying (off screen) and going back to edit it again, it goes back to Medium size:

[image: Changing to Automatic size, applying (off screen) and going back to edit it again, it goes back to Medium size]

Selecting other sizes which are not the automatic ('Small - about 5 items' and 'Large - about 30 items') will work fine and maintain the size, but only not the automatic. I tried the same on other Site and it's having the same behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried testing this on our SharePoint online site and I am able to reproduce this issue related to document library web part on modern experience site pages.

When I am selecting **Autosize - fit to number of items** under Size property in document library web part settings (properties pane) and republishing the site page, it get changed to **Medium - about 15 items** option automatically.

I think this is an issue at Microsoft's end. So, I will suggest you to raise a support ticket with Microsoft directly and report this behavior.

Follow this documentation for same: [Get M365 Support - Online Support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/get-help-support?view=o365-worldwide#online-support)

Comment: Thanks, indeed seems to be a bug. Now it's quite frustrating to not be able to ask for support because I'm not admin on my domain.

Comment: It seems last Sharepoint update corrected this issue, could you check it as well, Ganesh? Thank you.

Comment: I just checked and it is working fine for me now. It is keeping "Autosize - fit to number of items" selection as expected after publishing the page.